# How to permanently save SSH Key passphrase in Gitkraken?

Tags: gitkraken

I'm using [Gitkraken](https://www.gitkraken.com) and it keeps forgetting my SSH Key passphrase after every restart of the app. I've tried `ssh-add` with the Gitkraken CLI/Terminal, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make Gitkraken remember the SSH Key passphrase in between restarts. Can somebody educate me how to do this?

[image: Enter passphrase for SSH key prompt]

Comment: According to gitkraken Support, this is a feature and not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using the local SSH agent on Mac (Ventura OS):
[SSG Agent parameter location in Gitkraken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKkJa.png)

And prior to that I had to load automatically my passphrase in my .zshrc (not sure if it's mandatory to make it work with Gitkraken):

```
ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```